# After the phugoid mode subsides, in the steady state, why is there a small increase instead of decrease in the flight path angle?

Tags: climb, elevator

In the book [Dynamics of Flight](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/2.4126?journalCode=jgcd), I came across the following statement in Chapter 7, Section 7.7: Response to elevator

> The flight path angle is seen to be almost unchanged - it increased by about one-tenth of a degree. The reason for an increase instead of the decrease that would be expected in normal cruising flight is that at this flight condition the airplane is flying below its minimum-drag speed.

The above statement is actually explaining the below scenario: the phugoid mode response when elevator  displacement is one degree down.
[image]

Q. I know that

[image: formula]

As shown in the blockquote statement, if the airplane is flying below its minimum-drag speed then drag will be high (referring to the power curve), resulting a decrease in the flight path angle [image: formula_1] negative. Then why is the book mentioning an increase in the flight path angle. Please correct my chain of thought.

Thank you!

Comment: Please put your answers in answer, and use comments for clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the step change of the elevator the aircraft was in quasi-static stable flight: flying at a constant horizontal flight path angle ($\gamma = 0$) and no logitudinal acceleration.

After the step input on the elevator (1 degree down) is applied, the phugoid starts and slowly decays towards the new static equilibrium.

- The new elevator position causes a pitch down moment.
- Since the aircraft is longitudinally stable, the aircraft tends to pitch up at higher speeds.
- The new static equilibrium is thus found at a higher speed, such that the pitch down moment from the new elevator position is compensated for by the pitching up moment from the higher speed.

Since the orginal equilibrium was at a speed below the minimum drag speed, at the new (higher) speed, the drag will be *lower*. Assuming the engine provides the same thrust at the higher speed, the flight path angle

$$\gamma = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{T-D}{W}\right)$$
will now be positive, because the term $(T-D)$ is now positive.